# Hyperlink issue with webkit rotation.

Tags: css, webkit, iphone

We are rotating page by "-webkit-transform:rotate(90deg) scale(1.25,0.87) ; overflow:hidden;". All works well except that Hyperlinks on my page are shown as bar.

The reason is simple, after we rotate the page, the hyperlinks are applied which begins from left to right, since the page have been rotated, the links appears as bar.

Any idea how can we resolve this?

Note: This is on iPhone safari browser.

Comment: Think we have to apply css after the page load, for this, Not able to apply below css, webkit thing is not working, I tried using <style type="text/css"> body {-webkit-transform:rotate(90deg) scale(1.25,0.87) ; overflow:hidden;} </style> which is working. but below is not working: $(document).ready(function() { $(body).css("-webkit-transform","rotate(90deg) scale(1.25,0.87)"); });